# Empty search results Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, laravel-form

I am making a simple search engine in which, If the selected list from the dropdown would match with the one inside the 'destinationto' column from the database then it would fetch all the items inside that row. But when I hit the find button, it would not return any item from the database. It would be giving me an empty array.

```
 object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[141]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

What have I done wrong?

Here are the snippets

**OnewayflightControllers.php:**

```
 public function onewayflightresults()
 {
  $destinationto = Input::get('destinationto');
  $results = Oneways::where('destinationto','=',$destinationto)->get();   
  var_dump($results);
 }
 public function onewayflight()
{ 
  $onewaysfrom = DB::table('oneways')->distinct()->lists('destinationfrom');
  $onewaysto = DB::table('oneways')->distinct()->lists('destinationto');
  return View::make('content.onewayflight')->with(['destinationfrom'=>$onewaysfrom,'destinationto'=>$onewaysto]);
}
```

**onewayflight.blade.php**:

```
{{ Form::label('destinationto','To: ') }} 
{{ Form::select('destinationto', $destinationto)}}
```

Comment: It seems at the moment that you have no rows that have in `destinationto` value you fill in the form. Otherwise show us what you fill in, what is `var_dump` of `$destinationto` and what data you have in your table

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I have edited my question sir. I have tried var_dump on everything, only the $destinationto gives me no results. What could be the mistake I've made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a guess but you should make sure you have only one form element with name `destinationto`

If you have in form for example

```
{{ Form::label('destinationto','From: ') }} 
{{ Form::select('destinationto', $destinationfrom)}}

{{ Form::label('destinationto','To: ') }} 
{{ Form::select('destinationto', $destinationto)}}
```

If you think it's ok, you should add `var_dump($destinationto);` to your function to make sure value is what you expect

**EDIT**

I thought `select` will use values as keys but it's not so you should probably do something like that:

```
$onewaysfrom = DB::table('oneways')->distinct()->lists('destinationfrom','destinationfrom');
$onewaysto = DB::table('oneways')->distinct()->lists('destinationto','destinationto');
```

and not:

```
$onewaysfrom = DB::table('oneways')->distinct()->lists('destinationfrom');
$onewaysto = DB::table('oneways')->distinct()->lists('destinationto');
```

Comment: I have double check my forms and there is only one element with the name destinationto on it. Tried changing names which are totally different and var_dump it, but still nothing happens. It returns  'destinationfrom' => string '0' (length=1)
  'destinationto' => string '0' (length=1)